# How to determine that multiple js have been dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, dom

It's my js:

```
const map = new Map();
jsonData.list.forEach(function (item) {
if (!map.get(item.type)) {
  usedLaterScript = document.createElement('script');
  usedLaterScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  usedLaterScript.src = 'js/component/' + item.type + '.js';
  document.body.appendChild(usedLaterScript);
  map.set(item.type, item.type);
 }
});
```

jsonData:[{"type":"input"},{"type":"radio"},{"type":"select"}]

I want know when all js(like input.js,radio.js,select.js) was loaded,then I can do next

Comment: Are you wanting for document ready?

Comment: @ChrisCousins no,actually not,My page don't have ready document

Comment: Does `dynamicLoadJs.js` load `input.js`?  If it does, can you not simply make that also load `component1.js` *after* `input.js` is loaded?

Comment: @Archer I want do this, but I didn't know when the input.js end up loading,because the forEach

Comment: You'll need to modify your question as it doesn't really illustrate your problem.  Have a read of this -> **[mcve]**

Comment: @Archer I had reedit the question,is my description clear?

Comment: No, that's not helped at all I'm afraid.  Hopefully someone will understand and be able to help you out - good luck :)

Comment: @Archer anyway,thank you very much!

Comment: @Archer Hi,I reedit my question,That's the nature of the problem

Answer (score 1):

It could take time to load a dynamic added JS file. so you can bind a callback to the script tag like below, I load JQuery dynamically here.

```html
<script>
let usedLaterScript = document.createElement('script');
usedLaterScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(usedLaterScript);
usedLaterScript.onload = function() {
  if(allScriptsLoaded) {
    allScriptsLoaded();
  }
}; 

</script>
<script>
  allScriptsLoaded = function() {
  
    console.log("Jquery loaded",$);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: actually, in my project ,jquery load in the end,so I want use javascript to load other js

Comment: Just take this code as an example. you may not have to load Jquery at all

Comment: because I should dynamically load js , like:
loadJsArray.list.forEach(function(item){
  loadJs area;
});
so I don't know when they all end load

Comment: Its possible if you know the count of all js file to be loaded, just call the `allScriptsLoaded ` and keep a counter in that function.